# Visual Studio only publishes hostingstart.html to Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, hosting, visual-studio-publish

I have two ASP.Net Project. Project A is an earlier/older version of Project B. I used the `publish` functionality of Visual Studio to publish the .web project to Azure. Project A seems to get published successfully, and I can go to its Azure website in Chrome. But project B seems to succeed but when I browse to its site, I get a default Azure page stating "`Your App Service is up and running`".

Within Azure, I then go to `Project B` -> `Development Tools` -> `Console` and I simply enter `ls` to list the root directory contents. I simply get `hostingstart.html`.

When I do the same with Project A, I get: `App_Readme` `Content` `Global.asax` `Images` `NewImages` `Scripts` `Views` `Web.config` `bin` `favicon.ico` `hostingstart.html` `packages.config`

When I did the publish, I had Visual Studio running in Administrator Mode.

Also when I use `IIS Express` to locally deploy/publish, both sites load up and work fine.

I did not originally work on the two Projects. I simply inherited them, so I wouldn't know what was changed between A and B.

Is there something I have to enable in Project B to allow all the required files to be included in the publish?

Comment: Are you sure you're deploying to the correct Azure Web App? What does the `Web Publish Activity` Window in Visual Studio say? Try publishing it to disk locally so you can see what comes out of the publish task.

Comment: @rickvdbosch I may now have been. I have now gone `Publish`->`New Profile`->`App Service`->`Publish`->`Enter details`->`Publish`. This seems to work now. I don't remember if I was going through the same steps before.

Comment: @pnizzle, if you find a way to resolve the issue, please post it as answer, so others can easily find it.

Comment: @axfd thanks for the advice. I haven't done the process in my previous comment enough times to surely and confidently provide it as an answer as yet. I will be sure to do that when I am.